# How to get ip from request in java?

Tags: java, request, ip, httprequest

I have uploaded my code on server.

I am using:

```
 String ipAddress1 = FrameworkUtil.getServletRequest().getHeader("Remote_Addr");
 System.out.println("Remote_Addr ipAddress===>"+ipAddress1);

 String ipAddress = FrameworkUtil.getServletRequest().getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
 System.out.println("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR ipAddress==>"+ipAddress);

  if (ipAddress == null) {
        ipAddress = FrameworkUtil.getServletRequest().getRemoteAddr();
        System.out.println(" getRemoteAddr ipAddress=>"+ipAddress);
    }
```

I am getting:

```
 Remote_Addr ipAddress===>null
 HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR ipAddress==>null
 getRemoteAddr ipAddress=>127.0.0.1
```

But in google myip give me: `233.233.22.331`

What should I  do to get it in java ??

Comment: 127.0.0.1 means your server is running on localhost

Comment: @JonnyHenly but what should I do to get request IP ? ie from which IP the request came.

Comment: Addition to all the X-Forwarded-For-Posts: Those Header Attribues can be set by proxies, but it's not mandatory. The behavior of the Proxies can change by changing the protocol, so HTTP protocol will list the IP of the Client, which is connected to the proxy, but will not, if it's HTTPS. Depending on what you want to accomplish, I would not recommend that your application depends on the X-Forwarded-For header.

Answer (score 1):

Below should help you if you want to get IP from request :

```
    String ip = null;

    if (request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For") != null) {
        String xForwardedFor = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
        if (xForwardedFor.indexOf(",") != -1) {
            ip = xForwardedFor.substring(xForwardedFor.lastIndexOf(",") + 2);
        } else {
            ip = xForwardedFor;
        }
    } else {
        ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
    }

    System.out.println("Request from IP : "+ip);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will return you your LAN IP(ServerIP)

```
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println("Current IP address : " + ip.getHostAddress());
```

For java web applications. If you want your visitor's IP

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
if (ipAddress == null) {
    ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
}
System.out.println("ipAddress:" + ipAddress);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet will give you IP address.

```
String ipaddress = req.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
            if (ipaddress == null) {
                ipaddress = req.getRemoteAddr();
            }
    return ipaddress;
```

Comment: that's not always correct. the x-forwarded-for header might contain a list of IP. so this code might return a list of IPs instead of a single IP address